# The fine line between 3d and CAD

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that we are getting a lot of [questions like this one](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/3198/reducing-amount-of-material)

Which really are CAD / Mech engineering questions. I will note this person needed several rewrites of his question. Though I am not sure asking for Hollywood 007 scifi computer automagic is focused enough for the group... we can ignore that bit... But it is clear after a few revisions that he is looking for cad help.

Where do you all think we draw the line? As CAD is very closely coupled with 3d. I could see questions such as "how to I render this so it prints well" as a valid question. I am not sure asking for CAD auto processing software really should be topics we tackle. Or do we want to be inclusive to most non specific CAD questions, and let the members who are strong in that area handle it?

Answer (score 3):

I see your point in how CAD modelling only is an indirect match for this site; however, since it falls naturally into the workflow of 3D printing, it is indeed something most of our users have experience with. Furthermore, I believe many users get introduced to CAD through 3D printing, which again could make 3D Printing SE a natural place to turn back to.

In my opinion, I think we should allow these types of questions - at least for now. I don't see them as a problem due to their low frequency, and I think we generally manages to produce sensible answers.

There is also issue that there currently are no other Stack Exchange sites that focus on general CAD. There is always [Blender SE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/), but it would again be somewhat off topic there as well. Perhaps we could find some relevant beta site to direct pure CAD questions to?

Comment: At some point there is a line.. Maybe it is when we get to platform (I.E. solid works tool, autocad filter) specific question, or maybe that is too far and we want to draw the line before that. I am not sure.

Comment: I agree that CAD questions are mostly on-topic. However, only if generally related to 3D printing, or possibly with intent to 3D print the model.